# React Testing Library Mock function not called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am pretty new to testing and attempting to write what should be a simple test for our project...

```
test('Attempt Login', async () => {
   const submitHandler = jest.fn( ()=> console.log('hello'))

  const { debug, getByText, getByTestId, getByPlaceholderText } = render
    (
    <Router>
        <LoginPage submitHandler={submitHandler} />
    </Router> 
    )

    fireEvent.change(getByPlaceholderText("Enter Username"), {
      target: { value: "admin" }
    });

    fireEvent.change(getByPlaceholderText("Enter Password"), {
      target: { value: "Password" }
    });


    fireEvent.click(getByTestId("login-btn"));

    expect(submitHandler).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

My button inside of login

```
   <Button data-testid="login-btn" type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary"
   onClick={(event)=>submitHandler(event)}>
```

the testing error

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      45 |     fireEvent.click(getByTestId("login-btn"));
      46 |   
    > 47 |     expect(submitHandler).toHaveBeenCalled()
         |                           ^
      48 | })
      49 | 
      50 |
```

Thanks in advance for any help.  I spent way too long on this already -_-

EDIT: attempting to test for the results of clicking the login button

Heres what I'm going trying:

```
mock an Axios call to the login route
await waitForElement getByText('home')
expect getbytext('home')
```

Am I on the right track?

Do I need to import the redirect page component and place it inside the router? for example the  component for it to redirect to it?

Comment: I tried recreating the minimal example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-pine-5185k and it worked (see `Tests` tab on the right). It might be a problem with a `Button` component that you use (could you tell where it is coming from) or with something in the other part of your LoginPage - hard to tell without the rest of the code.

Comment: I tried to re-create a version of my code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-morning-bldhe?file=/src/App.test.js

I have another problem though, the aftereach(cleanup) doesn't seem to be working and it keeps re-rendering ?

Comment: So I finally figured out what was wrong.  The example i was following was passing in the function submitHandler as a prop into login.

my login button has onClick={submitHandler}
if i change it to onClick={props.submitHandler} the test will pass.

the question is now im trying to call a function in login that is not passed in as a prop.  How do i Mock that function in testing..?

Comment: There is no way to mock this function in a form that I can see in your codesandbox. The one way is to move this function out of the component, into different file and then mock it in test, something like described here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules. However, I would strongly advise against doing it, as you would be mocking really low level code. Instead, why not, instead of verifying a function was called, just check the expected result. Not sure what would be in your case, but I see that you are redirecting to some page. Maybe this or something close?

Comment: I'm pretty new to testing, and I wanted to take it incrementally.  I was planning to test for the result once I figured out how to get this working properly.

you are correct it should redirect to a new page, but its not actully doing it.

Comment: Regarding your edit, yes that seems like a good track. As for router testing, you don't necessarly need to use the redirect page component. Depending on what you want to test. If you want to verify that correct element appears after redirect, then yes, but I usually just verify if current path is the one I should see after redirect. You can use `MemoryRouter` for this, please see this guide: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/testing

Answer (score 2):

You should use **waitFor** in this case:

```js
...
await waitFor(() => expect(submitHandler).toHaveBeenCalled())
...
```

More info [HERE](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor)

Comment: Been struggling with this for a few hours. Other tests in the same codebase did not have to use `waitFor` however this was the fix that helped these tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out, the problem is you are passing the `submitHandler` mock into `LoginPage` but you are not using that prop.

To answer your second question

> How do I mock a function not passed in as a prop?

Here is how you can mock functions imported from different files with `Jest`:

```js
import { submitForm } from './ajax.js'; // the function to mock
jest.mock('./ajax.js'); // jest mocks everything in that file

it('should call submitForm correctly', async () => {
  submitForm.mockResolvedValue({ loggedIn: true });
  render(<LoginPage />);
  
  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Login' }));

  expect(submitForm).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(await screen.findByText('You have logged in successfully')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

---

### Useful links

- [Mocking modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules)
- [Understanding Jest mocks](https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c)
- [mockResolvedValue](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue)